# How can I remove a bootstrap buttons hover effect?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've gotten an assignment to remove the hover effect of the following button:

Visit http://www.appsbayou.se, search for the text "Kontaktinformation". Above it there's a button, "Skicka" which has an ugly black hover effect. This style comes from existing css.

I'm using Chrome and even if I open up Devtools I can't nail down the style rule that does this effect.

How can I remove this black hover color or at least change it to a color of my choosing?

Comment: To fix this set your background-color to the bottom color of your button gradient on hover, something like &:hover { background-color:""}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to toggle the `hover` state inside the developer tools in order to view the CSS which is applied to the button on `hover` state. Adding this CSS to your stylesheet will fix the problem:

```
input[type=submit]:hover {
     background-position: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution of all the answers. Marking as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the toggling of hover state in developer tools, did not know that.

Comment: Idem for the toggling, I was really wondering where to do that

Answer (score 2):

You have these rules:

```
input[type=submit]:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #222; // Here is the black background-color
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 0 -15px; // moves the background
  -webkit-transition: background-position .1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position .1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position .1s linear;
  transition: background-position .1s linear;
}

.wpcf7-submit:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fb8800,#975200) !important; // remove this?
}
```

Simply change the backgound-color to your choice of color. I would also suggest removing the gradient hover and the background positioning if you only wish to change a color. (And of course then the transitions doesn't make much sense either. )

Answer (score 1):

Go into the `HTML` and you will see this line which is the button:

```
<input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit" value="Skicka">
```

Remove the `wpcf7-submit` to get rid of the orange. It changes the color of the button but it may be a solution.

Or go into the CSS file and change this attribute:

```
.wpcf7-submit {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb8800, #975200) !important;
}
```

The code for the orange is `#fb8800`

Answer (score 1):

remove this from the page

```
.wpcf7-submit:hover{
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fb8800,#975200) !important;
}
```

or do a search for it... find it... then kill it!

Answer (score 0):

In BS4 you also need to overwrite the `button:before` pseudo-selector to set opacity to zero, otherwise hover remains, so you will end up with something like:

```
button.greyed-out-disabled,
button.greyed-out-disabled:focus,
button.greyed-out-disabled:hover {
  background-color: #E3E3E3 !important;
  color: #9E9E9E !important;
  outline: none;
}

button.greyed-out-disabled:before {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0) !important;
}
```